# How to solve this problem in jupyter notebook im tryin to build a CNN to recognise image wether cat or dog?

Tags: python

First I type in this line of code.

import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Maxpooling2D, Dense, Flatten

#Then when I run it this code pops up.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8744\3701811808.py in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
      2 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
----> 3 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Maxpooling2D, Dense, Flatten

ImportError: cannot import name 'Maxpooling2D' from 'tensorflow.keras.layers' (C:\Users\User\anaconda3\new\lib\site-packages\keras\api\_v2\keras\layers\__init__.py)
```

What can i do to solve?

```
First I type in this line of code.

import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Maxpooling2D, Dense, Flatten

#Then when I run it this code pops up.
```

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8744\3701811808.py in 
1 import numpy as np
2 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
----> 3 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Maxpooling2D, Dense, Flatten

ImportError: cannot import name 'Maxpooling2D' from 'tensorflow.keras.layers' (C:\Users\User\anaconda3\new\lib\site-packages\keras\api_v2\keras\layers_*init*_.py)

```
What can i do to solve?
```

Comment: the below is the initial code and the above is the code that came out after i run initial code..sorry for the mixup..first time using this..

Comment: It's `MaxPooling2D`, not `Maxpooling2D`

Comment: @NickODell tqvm